# Realtime background blur

Tags: front-end, cells, style, stylesheet

Is it possible to have partially transparent cells (attached or docked) with live background blur? Something like this:

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
CreateWindow[
 DockedCells -> 
  Cell["XXXX", "DockedCell", Background -> Opacity[0.5]], 
 Background -> LightBlue]
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get blur without using `Dynamic`? Like you could do it with `Dynamic` and setting the `Appearance` of the `Cell` to be a bitmap (might need to layer a `Pane` but you can just inspect the top-bar on documentation notebooks to see how) but I have to imagine that would make scrolling a nightmare. Basically you could do this but I don't think there are fast filters unless somehow you can do that with a PNG/9-patch

Comment: Not that I can see... this is a challenge.

Comment: macos gives you window blur for free

Comment: I got it to work with transparency, but no way to do blur according to WRI